# How to convert this specific timestamp format to UTC in Redshift?

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timestamp strings that look something like the example here:
`2017-07-12T01:51:12.732-0600`. Is there any function/combination of functions I can use this to convert this to UTC accurately?

The output should be `2017-07-12 07:51:12.732000`. I've tried using `to_timestamp` and `convert_timezone`. Obviously, the latter failed, but so did the former and I'm at my wit's end. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert the string directly to timestamp and then set source timezone in `convert_timezone` function like this (note, offset sign is the opposite to timezone):

`select convert_timezone('UTC+06','utc','2017-07-12T01:51:12.732-0600'::timestamp)`

if `-0600` part is varying you can construct `'UTC+06'` part dynamically like this

```
with times as (
    select '2017-07-12T01:51:12.732-0600'::varchar(28) as ts_col
)
select convert_timezone('utc'+(substring(ts_col from 24 for 3)::integer*(-1))::varchar(3),'utc',ts_col::timestamp)
from times
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you! :)